# How to mass refresh records

Tags: apex, trigger, formula, process-builder, custom-field

Is there any way to mass refresh an object with records over 1 million? Based on the values of this object, the related parent records will be updated
I tried using formula field but that didnt work

As the records are over 1 million, I am not able to export them using Data Loader or workbench.

Can anyone let me know if there is any way to do so?

Comment: Declarative Roolup Summary? https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/wiki/Getting-Started-With-DLRS

Comment: or you have to write your own batch

Comment: Data Loader limit is 5,000,000; not 1,000,000 - you may need to use the latest V47+ data Loader